# JS - Remove a tag without deleting content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to remove a tag but leave the content in tact? For example, is it possible to remove the SPAN tag but leave SPAN's content there?

```
<p>The weather is sure <span>sunny</span> today</p> //original

<p>The weather is sure sunny today</p> //turn it into this
```

I have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608547/jquery-remove-form-tag-not-content) method of using replaceWith(), but it it turned the HTML into

```
<p>
  "The weather is sure " 
  "sunny"
  " today"
</p>
```

EDIT : After testing all of your answers, I realized that my code is at fault. The reason why I keep getting three split text nodes is due to the insertion of the SPAN tag. I'll create another question to try to fix my problem.

Comment: $("p").contents().unwrap()


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308366/remove-element-with-jquery-but-leave-text

Comment: how about using innerHtml? Does it give the same result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unwrap text using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409117/how-to-unwrap-text-using-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery has easier ways:

```
var spans = $('span');
spans.contents().unwrap();
```

With different selector methods, it is possible to remove deeply nested spans or just direct children spans of an element.

Answer (score 14):

```
<p>The weather is sure <span>sunny</span> today</p>;


var span=document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]; // get the span
var pa=span.parentNode;
while(span.firstChild) pa.insertBefore(span.firstChild, span);

pa.removeChild(span);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it. Jquery is the most easy way:

```
//grab and store inner span html
var content = $('p span').html;
//"Re"set inner p html
$('p').html(content);
```

Javascript can do the same using element.replace. (I don't remember the regex to do the replace in one stroke, but this is the easy way)

```
paragraphElement.replace("<span>", "");
paragraphElement.replace("</span>", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just three text nodes instead of one. It doesn't make a visible difference does it?

If it's a problem, use the DOM `normalize` method to combine them:

```
$(...)[0].normalize();
```

Comment: Yup, it makes a difference for my purposes. I am storing the original DOM structure. Using replaceWith() alters the DOM structure slightly, so my code is now crashing :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

   var newLbl=$("p").clone().find("span").remove().end().html();
    alert(newLbl);

});​
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/7gWdM/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for a jQuery solution, here something that's a little more lightweight and focused on your scenario.

I created a function called `getText()` and I used it recursively. In short, you can get the child nodes of your `p` element and retrieve all the text nodes within that `p` node.

Just about everything in the DOM is a node of some sort. Looking up at the following links I found that text nodes have a numerical `nodeType` value of 3, and when you identify where your text nodes are, you get their `nodeValue`and return it to be concatenated to the entire, non-text-node-free value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue

```
var para = document.getElementById('p1')  // get your paragraphe 
var texttext = getText(para);             // pass the paragraph to the function
para.innerHTML = texttext                 // set the paragraph with the new text

function getText(pNode) {

    if (pNode.nodeType == 3) return pNode.nodeValue;

    var pNodes = pNode.childNodes        // get the child nodes of the passed element
    var nLen = pNodes.length             // count how many there are
    var text = "";

    for (var idx=0; idx < nLen; idx++) {   // loop through the child nodes
        if (pNodes[idx].nodeType != 3 ) {  // if the child not isn't a text node
            text += getText(pNodes[idx]);  // pass it to the function again and 
                                           // concatenate it's value to your text string  
        } else {
            text += pNodes[idx].nodeValue  // otherwise concatenate the value of the text
                                           // to the entire text
        }

    }

    return text
}
```

I haven't tested this for all scenarios, but it will do for what you're doing at the moment. It's a little more complex than a replace string since you're looking for the text node and not hardcoding to remove specific tags.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for that, the complete solution that has worked for me is:

Assuming we have:

```
<p>hello this is the <span class="highlight">text to unwrap</span></p>
```

the js is:

```
// get the parent
var parentElem = $(".highlight").parent(); 

// replacing with the same contents
$(".highlight").replaceWith( 
    function() { 
        return $(this).contents();
    }
);

// normalize parent to strip extra text nodes
parentElem.each(function(element,index){
    $(this)[0].normalize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it’s the only child span inside the parent, you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<p class="parent">The weather is sure <span>sunny</span> today</p>;
```

JavaScript:

```
parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
parent.innerHTML = parent.innerText;
```

So just replace the HTML of the element with its text.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `span` element and keep the HTML content or internal text intact. With jQuery’s [unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method.

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
              $("p").find("span").contents().unwrap();
            });
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>The weather is sure <span style="background-color:blue">sunny</span> today</p>
        <button type="button">Remove span</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

You can see an example here: [How to remove a tag without deleting its content with jQuery](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-remove-a-tag-without-deleting-its-content-with-jquery/)