# Check if I'm inside a cfwindow

Tags: coldfusion, cfwindow

I have an eror page on my site that get called whenever there is an error, sometimes from within a cfwindow and then I don't want to show the header and footer.

There are numerous cfwindows that I have that could generate this error ( working on that ... )

So instead of adding info to the parent window calling the cfwindow, I would simply (if possible) like to check on the error page

```
if(parent.cfwindow){remove the header and footer}
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: can you add an ID to your cfwindow? Then you can check for the ID and alter the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Per updated/clarified question (regarding this being for an error page)..

While javascript could still manage this, this is best suited for server-side.

I don't know what your `OnError` method looks like, or if you're using `application.cfm`. Here's how I'd accomplish this:

Instead of straight redirecting to `/error.cfm` or whatever the error page is, I'd:

```
<cfif not isDefined("url.inWindow")>
    <cflocation url="/error.cfm" addtoken="no" />
<cfelse>
    <cflocation url="/error.cfm?inWindow=1" addtoken="no" />
</cfif>
```

And within the error file, I'd do some `<cfif>`s based on the presence, of url.inWindow.

Javascript, and especially jQuery, have methods of doing this too, you could remove header and footer content and use `unwrap()`, to pull the content of the content area, as demonstrated here: [JS - Remove a tag without deleting content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848465/js-remove-a-tag-without-deleting-content).

---

I don't use `CFWINDOW` so am unfortunately unfamiliar with the nuances, and Railo supports it a bit differently

### Cold Fusion

The best ColdFusion route to achieve this may just be passing a url variable via the source link.

```
<cfwindow ... source="/demo/6/windowContentA.cfm?inWindow=1">
```

And then, within the document.

```
<cfif isDefined("url.inWindow")>The page is within a window</cfif>
```

### Javascript

The way to do this in javascript has to do with either (and this is the part I'm unable to test :/ without access to ACF.) checking either if the window is the top element (but that might not work).

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert((self==top ? 'in a popup' : 'not in a popup'));">Test link</a>
```

Or (if that doesn't work, checking if an element exists within the page as well.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(( document.getElementById('cf_window1') ? 'in a popup' : 'not in a popup'));">Test link</a>
```

Because CFWindow created an element named cf_window1, I used that for testing, but you should be able to use any element name. You could create an element specifically for this purpose if you wanted.

Although this how I managed to test...through some wizardry that doesn't matter, you could use similar javascript within a script tag to do something besides alert.

```
<script>
  if(self==top) {
    // The page is outside of a frame.
  }
</script>
```

Or the look-for-element route

```
<script>
  if(document.getElementById('cf_window1')) {
    // The page is within a frame.
  }
</script>
```

Neither route should be considered very secure. It's for convenience, and display, but you shouldn't consider them impenetrable, because they aren't.

Comment: thanks for attempting but please look at the revised question. Thanks

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks
 p.s.The url key  _cf_containerId is in every cfwindow, so there's no reason to create a new one, just check for that.